# what is RMSE in the results object in R package caret?

Tags: r, time-series, r-caret

Why result 1 is different from result 2 ? Intuitively I would think that truc$results$RMSE is the root mean square error of forecasts but I guess it is not.

```
library(caret)
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(15))
y <- x$x + rnorm(15)
myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",initialWindow = 10, horizon = 1, fixedWindow = FALSE, savePredictions=TRUE)
truc <- train(x,y,method = "lm",metric= "RMSE",trControl =myTimeControl,preProc = c("center", "scale"))
result1 <- sqrt(mean((truc$pred$pred-truc$pred$obs)^2))
result2 <- truc$results$RMSE
result1 
result2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invert mean and sqrt, you get the same result... Something's weird with caret's formula... Actually, you made an interesting observation...

```
result1 <- mean(sqrt((truc$pred$pred-truc$pred$obs)^2))
```

Comment: Hmm, it is not MSE but MAE then. Maybe I should tell the author. thanks a lot, I thought I was getting crazy !